# Re-creating Google+ app's UI

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm fairly new to Android development and planning to build a simple news reader app to further familiarize myself to the platform.

The problem is; I want each of the news-item to look like Google+'s post item below:

[image: img1]

Well, basically a big headline picture with a title and some description underneath.

I tried to re-create it using a `Button` (because the whole thing needs to be clickable by the user) while setting a drawable at the top of the text. It worked quite nicely.. until I decided to add more drawables to it:

[image: img2]

Here's my XML code (although I doubt anyone would need it):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/temp_jakarta"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you tell me why is this happening or maybe, suggest me another way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

*p.s., I'm pretty sorry about the link; as a new user, SO didn't allow me to post images just yet. :(*

Comment: You can't create that layout using only a `Button`. What you have as that Google+ post is a group of elements combined.

Comment: Do you want to create just the layout? Or do you also want to populate it?

Comment: @Ahmad, I'm planning to use that layout as `ListView` items. What do you mean by "populate"?

Comment: Could very well be a custom ViewGroup as well.  The Google+ ui is pretty spiffy, doubt there isn't something heavily customized in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put everything inside a RelativeLayout and place one relative to others (event on top, this doesn't matter at all) using the layout_below/above/left_of/right_of/... etc.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html for usage, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html for a complete reference of the RelativeLayout class and "Android Layout Tricks" series in the Developer Blog for some tips_

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html
- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-with.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check those out. :)